# Add custom addons in Weblate interface

Tags: weblate

Recent Weblate version dropped the use of script in favour of addons. There is a complete documentation on how to use existing addons, how to create a new addons (https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/addons.html?highlight=addon), however I have no idea how to add my addons and have it present in the web interface.

How does one add a new addons and have it available in the web interface?

Answer (score 0):

As you have also reported it [as an issue](https://github.com/WeblateOrg/weblate/issues/2235), the documentation got updated mean while to [cover this](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/addons.html#customizing-list-of-addons).